# Whats the best way of persisting data to Isolated Storage on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to persist objects into Isolated Storage, so far I could think of these ways:

1. Serialize them into an xml file when saving and then serialize them back when saving.
2. Use an Object DB. Doubt abounds about a good or recommended one (Examples are  [Perst](http://wmpoweruser.com/fully-supported-persistent-database-solution-now-being-offered-for-windows-phone-7/), [winphone7db](http://winphone7db.codeplex.com) and [Sterling DB](http://sterling.codeplex.com/))

Anyone can suggest some best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a basic guideline:

If you need the functionality of a database (relations, transactions, search, etc.) then you should use a database.

If you just need an object store, then you should just save your objects into Isolated Storage directly (serialising where necessary).

I haven't used each of the different DB options available but would probably go with Perst as it's the most established (there's also a good guide [here](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2010/06/07/perst-a-database-for-windows-phone-7-silverlight.aspx)), winphone7db is also not available yet.

Comment: Seconded. I've got two apps that have a very simple two or three "table" approach, and I'm just serialising objects and using linq.

Add http://www.db4o.com/ to your list of database options. I've not used it, but heard good things about it.

Comment: @Ben How do you go about serialising yoru objects?

Comment: I'm just storing them as properties on a singleton Database object. The Database class has load and save methods that use XmlSerializer to save and load the private fields.